# Windows 7 setup hangs after "Starting Windows..."-screen

Tags: windows-7, installation, freeze, setup

I'm having some trouble installing Windows 7. I need to install the OS from boot in order to split my C: into two different partitions, as this is not allowed when installing from inside Vista.

When I boot up from the install disc, I get the usual "Windows is copying files..."-screen, shortly followed by the "Starting Windows..."-screen with the animated window-logo or whatever. Then it looks as if the installation is about to begin with a blue screen and a cursor I can move around, but here it all stops. Nothing more happens, and the setup seems to hang. Not a single key on my keyboard has any effect, and all I am left to do is to abort and reboot.

I've tried to install using two different DVDs (not clones), and the same thing happens every time. What may be causing this, and how may I fix it?

---

Some of my hardware specs are as follows:

> Motherboard: Asus P5E X38 
> CPU: Intel
>   Core2 Duo E6850 3.0 Ghz 
> OS: Windows
>   Vista Ultimate 32bit 
> Keyboard:
>   Logitech diNovo Edge

.. need more?

And yes, I can still move my mouse around on the blue-ish screen, but I have not waited more than 10 minutes before giving up (gonna try waiting longer).

And no, I have not asked Microsoft.

And I have no idea how to reset the BIOS-settings.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Incredibly, [a post on the Windows Answers-forum](http://social.answers.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vistainstall/thread/64a2ca5d-c9cb-465a-af9f-7c3d68e4aba6) said what to do. And it worked!

> All I had to do was to disable the Floppy Drive-support in BIOS, reboot and install :)

Comment: After fidling with it, taking out all but one hard drive, unplugging all my usb stuff, removing my graphics card, unplugging my hard drive cooler.... it was the ^%#$%$#% floppy.

Comment: Why couldn't it just say: Yo Dude... you have a floppy? Get with the times man.

Comment: If it still does not work after disabling the floppy... see if your monitor is connected to the correct port on your gfx card. In my case, my TV was also connected and the installation showed up on the TV and hence the monitor was blank.

Answer (score 1):

Can the mouse still move when your keyboard stops to respond? How long did you keep the computer on, while its on this screen?

I suggest that you leave it at this screen for sometime (give it even 20 - 30 mins).

Also what are your hardware specs?

Comment: I've heard some reports that it's taken even up to 48h for a full install on some hardware... which is rediculous. As much as I love the new stuff in Vista and Win-7, MS really dropped the ball on their installers...

Comment: o_0 for me it took like just half an hour.. but i won't be suprised if that happened

Answer (score 1):

Try [this fix](http://backspacetab.com/2011/04/28/black-screen-after-starting-windows/):

1. Click Start > All Programs > Accessories
2. Right click on Command Prompt.
3. Select *Run as Administrator*.
4. Click Continue.
5. In the Command Prompt type:

   ```
   sfc /scannow
   ```

Answer (score 0):

If possible, try to burn the DVD from another computer and be sure to let it verify. Try booting the target computer with the least hardware possible and try to reset the BIOS settings for sure. If all else fails you you seem to have a hardware problem in one of your core components, try replacing them...

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record, I had the exact same problem. After having tried unsuccessfully to disable various devices from the BIOS (FDD, LAN controller, USB controller, etc.) I finally flashed the BIOS with the latest version from the vendor web site. And immediately after that operation, the installation of Windows 7 has worked like a charm.